# Mutual dependency MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Let's say I'm making a social app with MongoDB database, and I want users to be able befriend each other. Of course friendship is a mutual relation and user ids are integers. What would be the best approach?

1. Every user has a list of friend ids. Every time a bond is created/severed, both users' lists have to be updated.
2. Create join table 'friendship' containing IDs of 2 users. Every time bond is created I have to create two entries. 1->2 and 2->1
3. As no. 2, but always create only 1 bond with rule: lower_usr_id -> higher_usr_id. Assuming there are a lot of people and friendships. Wouldn't it save a lot of space and time?

Comment: Asking for a "best" approach is asking for opinions. There are multiple ways to tackle the problem. Also: You're asking about MongoDB, yet talking about join tables (a relational database concept). So this is unclear. If this something regarding *any* database technology, the solutions will be numerous.

Comment: By join table I simply mean a collection of objects that contain only two user IDs, so yes, it would work just as in relational databases. 
About 'best' approach: I assumed some solutions might perform way better than others.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're rather unclear about how MongoDB works. Joins aren't something that appears in MongoDB, and if you're trying to use MongoDB like a relational database you're doing it wrong.

I'm no expert on MongoDB, but I believe there are two common methods of modelling a one-to-many relationship:

1. Embedding one document inside another
2. Using references

Embedding a document inside another makes sense where the parent document in some sense "owns" the child document. For instance, in the context of a blogging application, a comment is owned by a post, so it might make sense to embed the comment inside the post.

For your use case, I don't believe that would be appropriate since the relationship is between objects of the same type. It would therefore make sense to record friendships as a reference to another object in the same collection.

Check out [this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/) for further details.